# JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF with AJAX, Javascript and Servlet in Java

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, syntax-error

I have an issue with my login request.

I get this error :

> [object Object]
>   parsererror
>   SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

The request is sent correctly (according to the network console) but when I'm receiving the response I get this error but I can't visualise the JSON object.

I'm using JavaScript, Ajax, jQuery and for the server side I'm using servlets in Java.

Here is my code

```
function connect(login, password){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url :"http://adress/log",
        data : "login=" + login + "&pwd=" + password,
        dataType : "json",
        success : traiteReponseConnexion,
        error : function(XHR, testStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("echec");
            alert(XHR + "\n" + testStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);}
        });
}

function traiteReponseConnexion(el){
    if(el.error != undefined){
        console.log("ici" +el.id);
    }else{
        alert("I'm here");
        window.location.href="main.jsp?id="+el.id+"&login="+el.login+"&key="+el.key+"";
    }
}
```

In my servlet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
    Map<String,String[]> pars = req.getParameterMap();
    if(pars.containsKey("log") && pars.containsKey("pwd")){
        String log = req.getParameter("log");
        String pwd = req.getParameter("pwd");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        JSONObject user = UserLogin.authentifiateUser(log, pwd);
        resp.getWriter().println(user);
    }
}
```

I don't understand where is the problem. I have no response from the server in 
the network console but in others services I don't seem to have this problem (logout for instance).

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I'm guessing that part comes from the URL, given the pseudo example `http://adress/log`. But good question.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing. The URL ends "/log" but the `data` property has "login=xxx&pwd=yyy". Server-side, `req.getParameter()` looks like it should be getting "login" not "log".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to send more than just `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`; you may well need [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#access-control-allow-methods-response-header) and/or [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header) as well, if a preflight is happening. If so, I believe you'll need to handle those in `doOptions` (not `doGet`).